# Avoiding password on command line (sudo)

Tags: perl, unix, ssh, sudo

```
use Net::SSH::Any;
use Data::Dumper;

# my $ssh2 = Net::SSH::Any->new(..);

my $cmd = "sudo -u postgres -p password perl -e 'print `whoami`'";
print Dumper $ssh2->capture({timeout => 15}, $cmd);
```

I would like to `sudo` on remote host, but don't like idea of having plain password on command line like in code above. Is there an alternative?

Comment: [password-less sudo](http://serverfault.com/questions/160581/how-to-setup-passwordless-sudo-on-linux) (there are security implications, of course)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot tnx, but I can't change sudo behavior

Comment: there is also `-S` switch which looks promising? http://superuser.com/a/67766/223664

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `sudo` installed on the remote machine is not very old, you can pass the password through stdin:

```
print $ssh2->capture({stdin_data => "$sudo_passwd\n"},
                     'sudo', '-Sk',
                     '-p', '',
                     '--',
                     @cmd);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I would recommend SSH keys with command restrictions and a role account for this task.  So, the role account would have an authorized_keys file that would look a bit like

```
command="postgres perl -e 'print `whoami`'" ssh-rsa <ssh key here>
```

So with that, you can ssh to the machine with the ssh key available and execute only the listed command.  Then you could eliminate passwords for local connection attempts from the role account and use SQL permissions to keep the role account as limited as you like.